# Why script doesn't get added to the path when using setup tools

Tags: python, setuptools

I have something likes this in my `setup.py` file. However, after installing the package, while the packages work, the scripts defined in bin directory, are not added to the Path. Note that I use a virtual environment. Therefore, I do `pip install` also from within the virtual environment, but from within the virtual environment, I still have to give the full path of `bin/myscripts.py` to run it.

```
from setuptools import setup

setup(
    name='MyLib',
    version='1.0.0',
    author='My name',
    author_email='My email',
    packages=['package1', 'package2'],
    scripts=['bin/myscript.py'],
    url='myurl',
    description='My library',
    install_requires=[
        'some1',
        'some2'
    ],
    long_description=open('README.md').read(),
)
```

Note that my folder structure is the following.

```
- bin
  - myscript.py
- setup.py
- package1
  - package1_lib1
  - package1_lib2
- package2
  - package2_lib
```

Comment: Where does the script end up after you install it?

Comment: Ah, I see it should be copied to the PATH. What does the PATH variable say when you're in the virtualenv?